# how to access xampp virtual host on mobile

Tags: apache, virtualhost

as i am a new in  developing,,therefore i want to know that how can a i access virtual host of xampp while i have accessed xampp localhost on my mobile deveice(I-phone)..And I have created virtual host in

`C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`  file as follow:

```
<VirtualHost yasir.com:80>
  ServerAdmin postmaster@dummy-host2.localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/yasir"
  ServerName yasir.com
  ServerAlias www.yasir.com
  ErrorLog "logs/yasir.com-error_log"
  CustomLog "logs/yasir.com-error_log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and also added the line

```
127.0.0.1    yasir.com
```

in

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you'll find [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to be the easiest solution.

Modifying your local host file will only affect that single PC, you would need to also modify the host file on your mobile (which may not be possible) and specify the external IP of your PC rather than 127.0.0.1 for what you've described to work.

Change `<VirtualHost yasir.com:80>` back to `<VirtualHost *:80>` first though and specify your ngrok domain as a `ServerAlias`.